# how to run a python web scraper in the background of php

Tags: php, python, mysql, mysql-workbench

I have been trying to figure out how to run a python web scraper from a PHP interface. The web scraper puts data into a mysql database, and the PHP interface echos the data in a table. I have spent a lot of time researching this, however the data never shows up in the table, even when I keep the data in the database, and reload the interface, no data shows up. Also When i call the python script in the terminal and then open the interface, the data arrives. Is there any way people could recommend doing this?
the first php script is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "3h test";
exec("python 3h.py");
?>
<form>
<input type="button" value="ViewCode" onclick="location="'python 3h.py'>
</form> 
<a href="action.php">Run script.</a>
</body>
</html>
```

the python crawler is:

```
from urllib import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pymysql.cursors

# Webpage connection
page1 = urlopen("http://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-    chart/19800203/7501/")
page2= urlopen("http://www.officialcharts.com/charts/")
# Grab title-artist classes and store in recordList
bsObj0 = BeautifulSoup(page1,"html.parser")
bsObj1 = BeautifulSoup(page2,"html.parser")

recordList0 = bsObj0.findAll("div", {"class" : "title-artist",})

recordList = recordList0 + bsObj1.findAll("div", {"class" : "title-artist",})
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='root',
                         password='******',
                         db='crawler database',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        for record in recordList:
            title = record.find("div", {"class": "title",}).get_text().strip()
            artist = record.find("div", {"class": "artist"}).get_text().strip()
            sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` (`title`,`artist`) VALUES (%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(artist,title))
    connection.commit()
finally:
    connection.close()
```

the python script is named 3h.py

the final php script is to long for me to bother typing out, this is the core:

```
 <?php
 $no     = 1;
 $total  = 0;
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
 {
 echo '<tr>
 <td>'.$no.'</td>
 <td>'.$row['itemName'].'</td>
 <td>'.$row['itemCost'].'</td>
 </tr>';
 $no++;
 }?>
```

Comment: If you want to know what is wrong with your code: maybe think about putting code-samples in your question. And you could do some debugging: does the PHP script gets called? If so: what does it do?

Comment: every script is being called, but the data is not arriving in the database. eventually what I want is a button that runs the web crawler and links me to the php page that displays the contents of the table.

Comment: You have to offer some code for anyone to help. Maybe make a "minimum working example" (or rather "not working") on github and link it here. If you don't show us any of your code we can hardly find bugs in it...

Comment: @MichaelI have added some code like you suggested, if you could have a look at it that would be great.Thanks!